# Rounding edges for images in a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SharePoint list with a column populated with pictures, however I would like to round the edges of said pictures.

I tried the solution I found [in this blog post](https://blogs.u2u.be/u2u/post/sharepoint-column-formatting-rounded-images), but it's not working for me.

Here's the JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes": {
                "src": "@currentField"
            },
            "style": {
                "width": "100px",
                "border-radius": "25px !important"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This does absolutely nothing to change the image CSS. If I could access the field to begin with that would be a start but I can't seem to find the correct JSON formatting to do so.

I have also tried without the `!important` and changing `px` to `%`, etc. Nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using **Image** column you have to change the JSON like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "attributes": {
        "src": "@currentField.serverRelativeUrl"
      },
      "style": {
        "width": "100px",
        "border-radius": "50%"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You will get image URL using `@currentField.serverRelativeUrl`.

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Update from Comments**:

You are applying formatting at wrong place.

1. On format panel, select **Format columns**
2. Choose your image column ("Photo" in your case) in **Choose Column** dropdown
3. Paste the JSON below & Save.

[image]

Comment: Hello Ganesh. Thank you for your answer, however the issue remains. I don't know if this will help but here's the json from the Gallery version of the list:

`"src": "[$Photo.serverRelativeUrl]"`  

I have tried @currentField.[$Photo.serverRelativeUrl] but also nothing

Comment: If you are formatting the "Photo" column, then you don't need to mention the column name in JSON. You can directly access the column using `@currentField`. So, `@currentField.serverRelativeUrl` should work for you.

Comment: And if you want to refer column by it's name. Make sure you are using correct [internal name](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html) of your column in JSON.

Comment: That makes sense but indeed it is not working. Here's proof: https://imgur.com/a/JDcEEGv. Edit: I am clicking "Preview" of course, and have tried saving with these settings and reloading page. Nothing

Comment: I also tried with different file formats: jpeg/jpg, png, svg. Nothing changed

Comment: Check updated answer. It should work for you.

Comment: Yep worked perfectly! Thank you!!